# Marker out of canvas TomTom

Tags: canvas, maps, marker, tomtom

You can have a look at this IMG to understand quickly the issue:

[Example IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXTts.png)
This appens when you drag with mouse on the map. Thanks

Comment: Not enough details to reproduce this. Give some code and/or record a video.

Comment: Hey! Did you find an answer to this question? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add style to the marker:

```
#marker {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: your-marker-icon-here.svg;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:

Don't forget to import `style.css`.

In react it's `import '@tomtom-international/web-sdk-maps/dist/maps.css'`

More information here: https://developer.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-web-js/documentation